# ElasticSearch : After install plugin elasticsearch-head

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an issue here, I don't know if it is normal or not.
But I thinks something is lake somehere, after installation of plugin elasticsearch-head, I got this logs when launch url "http://localhost:9200/_plugin/head" on my browser, after googling I don't know how to handle it :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No feature for name [_status]
at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.get.GetIndexRequest$Feature.fromName(GetIndexRequest.java:82)
at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.get.GetIndexRequest$Feature.convertToFeatures(GetIndexRequest.java:95)
at org.elasticsearch.rest.action.admin.indices.get.RestGetIndicesAction.handleRequest(RestGetIndicesAction.java:77)
at org.elasticsearch.rest.BaseRestHandler.handleRequest(BaseRestHandler.java:54)
at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.executeHandler(RestController.java:207)
at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:166)
at org.elasticsearch.http.HttpServer.internalDispatchRequest(HttpServer.java:128)
at org.elasticsearch.http.HttpServer$Dispatcher.dispatchRequest(HttpServer.java:86)
at org.elasticsearch.http.netty.NettyHttpServerTransport.dispatchRequest(NettyHttpServerTransport.java:348)
at org.elasticsearch.http.netty.HttpRequestHandler.messageReceived(HttpRequestHandler.java:63)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.elasticsearch.http.netty.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.messageReceived(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:60)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:88)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpChunkAggregator.messageReceived(HttpChunkAggregator.java:145)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:108)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:459)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:536)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:75)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[2015-09-18 22:43:14,748][INFO ][rest.suppressed          ] /_status Params: {index=_status}

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No feature for name [_status]
at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.get.GetIndexRequest$Feature.fromName(GetIndexRequest.java:82)
at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.get.GetIndexRequest$Feature.convertToFeatures(GetIndexRequest.java:95)
at org.elasticsearch.rest.action.admin.indices.get.RestGetIndicesAction.handleRequest(RestGetIndicesAction.java:77)
at org.elasticsearch.rest.BaseRestHandler.handleRequest(BaseRestHandler.java:54)
at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.executeHandler(RestController.java:207)
at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:166)
at org.elasticsearch.http.HttpServer.internalDispatchRequest(HttpServer.java:128)
at org.elasticsearch.http.HttpServer$Dispatcher.dispatchRequest(HttpServer.java:86)
at org.elasticsearch.http.netty.NettyHttpServerTransport.dispatchRequest(NettyHttpServerTransport.java:348)
at org.elasticsearch.http.netty.HttpRequestHandler.messageReceived(HttpRequestHandler.java:63)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.elasticsearch.http.netty.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.messageReceived(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:60)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:88)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpChunkAggregator.messageReceived(HttpChunkAggregator.java:145)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:108)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:459)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:536)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:75)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)

Ubuntu 14.04    (64 bits)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which version of elasticsearch ? head doesn't seem to be supporting 2.0 since [_status](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-status.html) has been removed in 2.0

Comment: There is [work in progress](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head/pull/202) to support ES 2.0. You should subscribe to that PR so that can get informed. Or you install ES 1.7.2 or lower and it will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The _status API has been deprecated since the version 1.2.0 of Elasticsearch.

This was replaced by the _recovery API.

You can update your plugin head by replacing the term "_status" to "_recovery" in the four files below:

- *YOUR_ES_PATH*/plugins/head/src/app/services/clusterState/clusterState.js
- *YOUR_ES_PATH*/plugins/head/src/app/ui/indexSelector/indexSelector.js
- *YOUR_ES_PATH*/plugins/head/src/app/ui/header/header.js
- *YOUR_ES_PATH*/plugins/head/_site/app.js

Regards,
Alain

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for checking @keety and @Val, it was a compatibility issue.
Now solved by downgrading my elasticsearch to the latest stable version.
From version Elasticsearch 2.0.0-beta2 to 1.7.2.